# How to use IN command with data from a column

Tags: sql

I am using STUFF to get the data in a column as a list and using it in PIVOT. Now, how to use the value got from STUFF in pivot?

```
SELECT  @listCol = STUFF(( SELECT '], [' + [CategoryName] 
    FROM OnCall_Category 
    FOR 
    XML PATH('') 
), 1, 2, '') + ']' ;

SELECT 
    EmployeeSID,
    ManagerSID
    FROM
    t1
    PIVOT (
         Min(RequestCount) 
         FOR Category IN @listCol  //intended operation
    ) AS t2
```

Comment: Dynamic SQL would solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

`@listCol` is a string, whereas you want a list of values. Therefore, use dynamic SQL to construct the `PIVOT` query, and then execute it.

```
declare @query nvarchar(max0
set @query = N'SELECT EmployeeSID,ManagerSID FROM t1' 
             + N'PIVOT (Min(RequestCount) FOR Category IN '
             + @listCol  
             + N') AS t2'

exec sp_executesql @query
```